# jQuery select title attribute x, then scroll to #title

Tags: jquery, selector

My question is how can I scroll to a certain position onClick to an id #title using jQuery without having to repeat the same lines in the code over and over.

Just like this:

```
//Scroll from here (onClick)

<span title="something"><element>Link</element></span>

.
.
.

// to here 

<div id="something"></div>
```

I've tried something like this, but it did not work:

```
$(document).ready( function(x) {

                    $("span[title='" + x + "']").click(function() {
                        window.parent.$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#" + x).offset().top - 10}, "slow");
                        return false;

                    });

                });
```

...which is a modified version of this, which works fine, but requires the same code to be repeated again and again:

$(document).ready( function() {

```
                $("span[title='titlex']").click(function() {
                    window.parent.$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#titlex").offset().top - 10}, "slow");
                    return false;
                });
                $("span[title='titley']").click(function() {
                    window.parent.$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#titley").offset().top - 10}, "slow");
                    return false;
                });
```

});

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a class to your span element:

```
$("span[title]").click(function() {
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#" + $(this).attr('title')).offset().top - 10}, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You're welcome (by the way, in the future, when someone helps, don't forget to indicate that the answer is approved by checking it)! And if you need explanation, just say the word.